# Analogue of spectral values of automorphisms in vN algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Is there any analog of studying spectral properties of automorphisms of von Neumann algebra? Does it make sense, if anybody knows please give a reference.

Comment: An analog in what?

Comment: Studying spectral properties and spectral measures

Comment: Well, the original setting is spectral properties and spectral measures, and you want an analogue for automorphisms of von Neumann algebras, if I understand correctly (this is not clear at all in the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but is the following of interest:

https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=348518
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123674900342

```
Arveson, William
On groups of automorphisms of operator algebras.
J. Functional Analysis 15 (1974), 217–243.
```

Arveson develops a notion of "spectral subspaces" for automorphisms (or more generally, one-parameter groups of isometries on Banach spaces).  The details are somewhat technical, but the paper is an easy read.